# Update textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery

Trying to get current data from textarea with jquery and replace it with what server returns. so far `q` value is picked up right, instead of updating it with server returned content, it just replaces it with `'&nbsp;'`

```
q = $('textarea#id_message').val();
alert(q)
$("textarea#id_message").val('&nbsp;').load( '/process/url?html=' + q );
```

Update

I just tried it passing server data to test results `<div>`, this does work, `<textarea>` does not.

```
$( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '/process/url?html=' + q );
```

Comment: alert(q) works fine, it shows data of textarea

Comment: Type into a browser yourdomain.com/process/url?html=[whatever q is] and see if you get anything back.

Comment: process url when called on its own works fine

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) on an element, you're calling [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on the same element later [to put the response in there (jQuery core source code here)](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L60), but that doesn't work on inputs, you need [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).  To do this, you can use [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) with a callback, like this:

```
var val = $('#id_message').val();
$.get('/process/url?html=' + val, function(data) {
  $('#id_message').val(data);
});
```

You could also sanitize the input if the server accepts POST by passing the params as an object like this:

```
$.get('/process/url', {html: $('#id_message').val()}, function(data) {
  $('#id_message').val(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the `load` command is failing because you are passing the value of the textarea to as a GET parameter without any sanitation.

using `escape(q)` *might* help, but we'd need to know what happens server side to tell for sure.

Comment: escape(q) did not work, the server side seems like it is working fine

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
p
{
 margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
 font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
</head>
q returns value

<body>
<p>Hello, World!</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This is a bit much for a GET request. Can't you send it via a POST Ajax Request?

Comment: and what does `/process/url?` return, given this?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the val() is causing problems. Does it work if you remove the `.val('&nbsp;')` altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just use text or html function instead of val for textarea? AFAIR textarea doesn't have val attribute. It's just `<textarea>Text inside textarea</textarea>`